# How can I set PGPASSWORD automatically when i run a batch file for auto backup of my postgresql database in windows

Tags: database, postgresql, batch-file, cmd, backup

I have create a batch file and write code as per picture. But my problem is it is always asked my pgpassword though i have already define it first. I need a solution early. TIA.

```
set PGPASSWORD=123456 
pg_dump -U postgres -W -F c YBD_ERP_Latest > E:\DBBackup\db_backup_%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.backup
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) says:

> -W
> --password
>
> Force psql to prompt for a password before connecting to a database [...].

So even though you have defined the password in PGPASSWORD, you have also forced psql to prompt for a password.

--> just remove the `-W` flag from `pgdump` options